# TCP Socket Receive Incorrect Byte C

Tags: c, sockets

i am coding a multiplayer game and i met a trouble. I have the server side send a buffer by call send() func and client side receive data to a buffer by call recv() func(in a endless loop). The trouble is client side sometimes receive an incorrect byte(= byte of buffer i malloc before to use to receive). Im using nonblocking socket by use ioctlsocket(). Can you tell me what wrong in my idea? (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: As always, with questions asking why some code isn't working: **show code please**. See also [mcve].

Comment: From my experience, I can guess you send/receive just raw buffers of data, without any app-level protocol on top of them.

Comment: remember that TCP is stream oriented protocol, not message oriented. The message blocks you send are not the same size blocks that you receive. You need to wrap the stream up with a header indicating message length